# Get count of each locations by status

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables called `QueueTable` and `Location`,

`QueueTable` data as follows,

```
QueueID FkBranchID  AddedTime   Status
11001           10  2019-07-02  5
11002           10  2019-07-03  5
11003           10  2019-07-04  6
11004           10  2019-07-05  5
11005           20  2019-07-06  6
11006           20  2019-07-07  5
11007           20  2019-07-08  6
11008           20  2019-07-09  6
11009           20  2019-07-10  5
11010           30  2019-07-11  5
11011           30  2019-07-12  6
11012           30  2019-07-13  5
11013           30  2019-07-14  6
11014           30  2019-07-15  5
11015           40  2019-07-16  5
11016           40  2019-07-17  5
11017           40  2019-07-02  5
11018           40  2019-07-03  5
11019           40  2019-07-04  6
11020           50  2019-07-05  5
11021           50  2019-07-06  5
11022           50  2019-07-13  6
```

And `Location` table data as follows

```
BranchID    BranchName
10          Delhi
20          Karnataka
30          Telangana
40          Gujarat
50          Tamil Nadu
```

Now I need to retrieve the following output by joining tables

[image]

I tried this query and I know there are more wrong things,How to solve this

```
select b.BranchId AS ID, b.BranchName,count(lo.QueueID) as Count1 
from Location b
left outer join
(
select br.BranchId,l.QueueID 
from QueueTable l
LEFT OUTER join Location br 
on l.FkBranchId = br.BranchId
where  l.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY l.QueueID) lo on lo.BranchId = b.BranchId
```

But it throw an error

> Column 'Branch.BranchId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please don't post data as an image, it is all but useless to those you are asking for help from unless you're expecting the volunteers to transcribe it. Please take the time to post your data as tabular formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry sir, I'll never do it again, can you help me to solve this problem

Comment: *"I have **three** tables called `QueueTable` and `Location`,"* What's the 3rd? You only supplied 2 tables and your expected results.

Comment: Sure, but I need that data in a format I can consume; I can't use an image, so I can't help you. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu Its a mistake, I edited it

Comment: @Larnu It would be great if it was a DDL and DML statements, or even a prepared fiddle :)

Comment: Define _"But it's not working"_ please. Did you get an error? or something else? Also is there any other Status except 5 & 6?

Comment: @Larnu I updated my quetion sir

Comment: What about the error here don't you understand @Adam? This is one of the clearer ones from SQL Server. You have a `GROUP  BY` in your subquery, and no aggregation, and aggregation in your outer query, with no `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, group by BranchId, BranchName an count conditionally with a CASE statement the occurrences of 5 and 6:

```
select 
  l.BranchId AS ID, 
  l.BranchName,
  count(case q.Status when 6 then 1 end) as Count1,
  count(case q.Status when 5 then 1 end) as Count2  
from Location l left join QueueTable q
on l.BranchId = q.FkBranchId
where l.IsActive = 1
group by l.BranchId, l.BranchName
```

Comment: I have another column called `IsActive` in Location table, I need to only retrieve where `IsActive = 1` how can I do it also

Comment: Suppose `IsActive` also have In QueueTable, Then I need to also check its value,how can I check `QueueTable` isActive status also?

Comment: `where l.IsActive = 1 AND q.IsActive = 1`

Comment: When I add it as it is, no of rows are reduced,it cannot happened. only count can be reduced,but rows cannot be reduced, I think I need to check it in here `(case q.Status when 6 then 1 end)` can I check isActive in there?

Comment: `case q.Status when  6 AND q.IActive = 1 then 1 end` Can i use as this??

Comment: Yes you can:`case when q.Status = 6 AND q.IActive = 1 then 1 end` if it gives the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT L.BranchID,
L.BranchName,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) [Count1(5)], 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) [Count2(6)]
-- You can add more Column here based on Number of Status you have.
FROM Location L
LEFT JOIN QueueTable Q ON L.BranchID = Q.FKBranchID
WHERE Q.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY L.BranchID,L.BranchName
```

Comment: What if there is more status and not just 5 and 6? Also don't you think it's a `LEFT JOIN` instead?

Comment: OP's expected output indicates s/he only required calculation for 5 & 6 only.

Comment: @mkRabbani This works without errors, but if there is no location,which is not in the QueueTable , which are not returns, if location with no mapping to QueueTable , I need shows its counts columns as zeros

Comment: @Adam Script Updated.

Comment: @mkRabbani  I have `IsActive` column In QueueTable, Then I need to check its value and only retreive if  `IsActive = 1`,how can I check QueueTable isActive status also?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to this:

```
select
     a.branchid,
     a.branchname,
     (select count(*) from queuetable where fkbranchid=a.branchid and status=5) status_5_count,
     (select count(*) from queuetable where fkbranchid=a.branchid and status=6) status_6_count

from
     location a
```

You can execute this query live on this 
**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/409fb/10/0)**

Answer (score 0):

**USE** dynamic query to count the `status` specially when it's dynamic

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(CAST([status] AS VARCHAR))
FROM #QueueTable
GROUP BY [status]

SET @sql = '
select BranchID, BranchName, ' + @col + '
from (
    select l.BranchID, l.BranchName, FkBranchID, q.status
    from #Location l 
    join #QueueTable q on q.FkBranchID=l.BranchID)p
PIVOT(COUNT(FkBranchID) FOR status IN ( ' + @col + ' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY BranchID'

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
BranchID    BranchName  5   6
10          Delhi       3   1
20          Karnataka   2   3
30          Telangana   3   2
40          Gujarat     4   1
50          Tamil Nadu  2   1
```

Comment: What is the reason, can you explain me the reason?

Comment: It is specially helpful when there is new status come in your table as 7 and you won't need to change the query to display it's count, above dynamic code will consider this new status also.